# Firefox would not receive data from Window.postMessage

Tags: javascript, php, backend

I have a back-end code in PHP that will do authentication using social networks and a front-end code that will open a new window to load the HTML files of the authentication. The final callback window from the back-end will send an object in a postMessage() to the window opener. This works for any browser other than Firefox. Does any of you encountered this before and managed to fix it?

I have already tried to user window listener, with no success too.

```
login: function (url, provider) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      window.open(url + '/v1/user/login/' + provider, '_new', 'height=500,width=500');
    });
  },

  getLoginResponse: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      window.onmessage = function (e) {
        resolve(e.data);
      };
    });
  }

let data = '{{$data}}';
data = JSON.parse(data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'));

let opener = window.opener;
opener.postMessage(data, "*");
```

For other browser, the `resolve(e.data)` part works but not on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

`WindowEventHandlers.onmessage` is experimental and not officially supported on Firefox (at least it doesn't on v76) and therefore `window.addEventListener("message", cb`) won't work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onmessage